# django: Use different configuration for test database?

Tags: django, integration-testing

Can I specific a different configuration for the test database? Or alternatives simply use a different user in production?(how to manage that as settings file needs to be updated as well?) The testing requirements for postgresql require in my opinion too many privs like create DB and in my case I also need to create an extension upon db creation which means superuser privileges.

Comment: Have you considered to use an .env file? In settings.py you can load that and check for some var like:
if DEBUG:
[DB Settings for your local dev]
else:
[DB Production]

Or you just move these settings to the env file at all!

Answer (score 0):

This is very messy, but a valid workaround nonetheless. We use a snippet of code like this in  `settings.py` to run tests using a local sqlite3 database.

```
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv or 'test_coverage' in sys.argv: 
    DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
```